# What will binding or computed property have better performance?

Tags: ember.js

I have been on this case many times, i don't still know which is the best way to define the following object property.

option A

```
name: Em.Binding.oneWay(‘content.name’);
```

option B

```
 name: Em.computed(function(){ 
   return this.getPath(‘content.name’); 
 }).property(‘content.name’).cacheable()
```

Comment: What do your profiling tests say?

Comment: Which performance metric are you looking for?  How do you want to measure it?

Answer (score 2):

And what about simply:

```
nameBinding: 'content.name'
```

Comment: From the doc : `One way bindings are almost twice as fast to setup and twice as fast to execute because the binding only has to worry about changes to one side.`, so the optionA previously described as faster than your solution

Comment: I currently have Tom Dale just in front of me, let me paraphrase him: "this performance difference will certainly never be the bottleneck in your application / this is certainly premature optimization"... Have nothing to add on my side.

Comment: I agree with considering it as a premature optimization and I never want to invalidate Tom Dale's opinion, but I guess its still a little bit faster - as said in the doc -.

Comment: @MikeAski, here could be 2 different questions or perhaps i did not understand well.  My 2 options above could be a premature optimization, there is no much difference between them, however as louiscoquio mentioned oneWayBindings are faster than twoWays, could "to use oneWayBinding" also be considered a premature optimization?  I opened an [issue](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/959) regarding oneWay-twoWay bindings.

Comment: ppcano In your question, you don't precise what you want as the "best" way. So IMO, the best way is the @MikeAski's answer, which is the most readable and concise. If you encounter a performance issue in this binding, so I would prefer your OptionA, which is more readable than OptionB